# Android TranslateAnimation animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a compound view mixed by some buttons on it that is attached on top-right corner of screen with RelativeLayout. I want this view to animate to right when I click on "open-close" button on it and stays there until user selects/clicks one of its buttons or clicks again on "open-close" button and then it should animate to right and become invisible. The problem is that it animates to left and then it moves back to its original place! What should I do to solve this problem?

Code:

```
public class AlarmCommandComponent extends LinearLayout {

    ImageButton carOffButton;
    ImageButton carOnButton;
    ImageButton armButton;
    ImageButton disArmButton;
    ImageButton openCloseButton;
    LayoutAnimationController controller;
    Animation animation;

    public AlarmCommandComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.car_alarm_view, this);

        openCloseButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.alarmOpenCloseButton);

        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
        animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, //fromXType 
                0.0f,                       //fromXValue
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, //toXType
                -1.0f,                      //toXValue
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, //fromYType
                0.0f,                       //fromYValue
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, //toYType
                0.0f);                      //toYValue
        animation.setDuration(500);
        set.addAnimation(animation);
        LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.25f);
        this.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
        this.setPadding(0, 7, 7, 10);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        openCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openCloseButton_onClick(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void openCloseButton_onClick(View v) {
        this.startAnimation(animation);
    }

}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the animation resets the object to the initial state. You need to specify `fillAfter` to `true`:

```
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but it seems that my "open-close" button doesn't respond to clicks in this situation? Am I right?

Comment: The pre-Honeycomb animation framework only moves the visual part of the layout.  The physical location stays the same and you have to move it yourself.  Honeycomb introduced the Animator class, and more specifically the PropertyAnimator, which will both animate and physically move objects.

Comment: I am working on Android 2.1 so what should I do to move actual objects with animation not just a snapshot of them?

Comment: Either mess with the margins of the `View` or add an AnimationListener that physically moves the object within the layout on animation end (i.e. do not use setFillAfter).

Comment: Dear Jens, I have to use setFillAfter(true) (read the q&a again), so now is the only way to set new margins for layout?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the button work after translation you need to shift it physically as well to the new position. You can do this by changing the layout position programatically.

Set an animation listener & Inside onAnimationEnd do this -

```
  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

yourLayout.layout(newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom);

  }
```

To know more about the animation constraints that exists prior to honeycomb API read this - http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html

Comment: I did the job with Sliding Drawer and fading-in and out! I think that working with layouts in program, is not a good practice in medium to large scale apps.

Comment: But Sliding drawer has a constraint that it can be toggled from bottom to top & right to left. it doesn't work if you need your drawer to open from left to right OR from top to bottom. Anyways, good luck!